# javascript: Open an URL from an window.open page back in the original page

Tags: javascript, target, window.open

I'm opening a smaller web browser window from the "main" web page. The "child" window contains links like the following...

`<a onclick="javascript:window.open('http://someplace.com/','_blank');">Someplace</a>`

But instead of using target "_blank" I would like to use the name of the original, "main" web page window and open the links back in that window. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: have you tried window.opener.name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this example to help you solve your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.opener.document.write("<p>This is the source window!</p>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open 'myWindow'" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you suggest using `document.write` on `window.opener`?

Comment: this is just a ready-made example of what can be achieved and how to achieve it. I think this helps @Bob Foster solve his problem, no?

Comment: Thanks @henser. That did help me follow the code and see what other things are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of window.open, you can use:

```
<a onclick="javascript:window.opener.location.href = 'http://someplace.com/';">Someplace</a>
```

Comment: Okay, duh, I wasn't aware of the window.opener function. Thanks.